# Converting postgresql timestamp to JavaScript timestamp in Python

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, flot

I have a postgre database with a timestamp column and I have a REST service in Python that executes a query in the database and returns data to a JavaScript front-end to plot a graph using `flot`.

Now the problem I have is that `flot` can automatically handle the date using JavaScript's TIMESTAMP, but I don't know how to convert the Postgre timestamps to JavaScript TIMESTAMP (YES a timestamp, not a date stop editing if you don't know the answer) in Python. I don't know if this is the best approach (maybe the conversion can be done in JavaScript?). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's not thing as "Javascript timestamp". There are Javascript `Date` objects, that's all. You can try to convert the timestamps to milliseconds since 1970-01-01, and use that value to create a Javascript `Date` object.

Comment: Whatever library you are using to implement `REST` should support this, so before you try to re-invent the wheel, see if the library supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [date_part](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) or extract in postgres to return a timestamp.

```
select date_part('epoch',mydatefield)*1000 from table;
```

Then you can just send that on over directly, noting that `epoch` is *seconds* since Jan 1, 1970, whereas JS wants *milliseconds*, thus the `*1000`.  If you need it to actually be a date, once you receive it in Javascript, you can convert it to a date by calling `new Date(timestamp_from_pg)`.

Note that flot can work off of timestamps as numbers, no need to actually create `Date` objects.

Comment: Thanks Ryley this is what i was asking, thank god you read the question before all the editors changed the timestamps for "date" in my question

Comment: Depending on your infrastructure, it might make sense to just get the timestamp from postgres and do the conversion to epoch in Python.  Personally, I try to keep all the conversions in Python to free up as many resources on the Database servers as possible. I know this type of conversion is a ridiculously trivial operation, but my database servers are always working harder than the web servers.  Also, depending on what you're using to interact with the database ( ie: drivers like psycopg2, orms like sqlalchemy, etc ) what you retrieve could be a string or datetime-like object for conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send a Python or Javascript "datetime" object over JSON. JSON only accepts more basic data types like Strings, Ints, and Floats.

The way I usually do it is send it as text, using Python's `datetime.isoformat()` then parse it on the Javascript side.